# Put contents of a folder into a zip using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I need to put the contents of a folder into a ZIP archive (In my case a JAR but they're the same thing).

Though I cant just do the normal adding every file individually, because for one... they change each time depending on what the user put in and it's something like 1,000 files anyway!

I'm using ZipFile, it's the only really viable option.

Basically my code makes a temporary folder, and puts all the files in there, but I can't find a way to add the contents of the folder and not just the folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

Python allrady support zip and rar archife. Personaly I learn it form here https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

And to get all files form that folder try somethign like

```py
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        #enter code here
```